# Proper selection of loops versus function versus object/class

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

When writing a program, my understanding as a hobbyist programmer is, there are three ways to accomplish most of the things:

- create loops
- create and use function
- create and use object

I am using javascript here to ask my question since I took learning on it about 2-3 weeks before. It is somewhat strange compared to what I was used to in python or MatLab in University but that's not the point. I often think what should be the good choice among three in particular application so I wanted to know your suggestion.

I wanted to create a list of array to subsequent use for plotting. The program is supposed to take coefficients of the equation, incremental step and the boundary for x-values. Below is the code (Sorry if I missed something below when changing to fit SO, but it was working some moments before!):

```
function array_creator(input_coeff,inc, boundary){
var bound=boundary||[0,1];
var eqn_deg=input_coeff.length-1;
var increment=inc;
var x_init=bound[0];
var y_val=0;
var graph_array=[];
while (x_init<=bound[1]){
    for(var i=0;i<input_coeff.length;i++){
        y_val=y_val+input_coeff[i]*Math.pow(x_init,eqn_deg);
        eqn_deg--;
            }

    new_arr=[x_init,y_val];
    eqn_deg=input_coeff.length-1;
    y_val=0;
    graph_array.push(new_arr);
    x_init=x_init+increment;
    }
return graph_array;
}
```

In above code, I have one nested loop which goes inside the while but I am used to writing codes that goes more than 3-4 deep in nesting and I cannot dig my own program a week after. So my question is, when should I know that it is time to implement separate function rather than having nesting or know the time to create an object. What are the gains and losses of breaking one big looped function into several function in terms of clarity and efficiency? At what point the creating of object becomes essential or is it just when I have to re-use the same code again.

When the only tool you have is hammer, everything looks like nail. When I started learning python after MatLab, I was so impressed by OO approach that I used to create classes in every situation whether needed or not. I think many SO newbies will be glad to find some systematic approach on this programming fundamentals.

Comment: So this question is about to be closed with the argument that it is opinion based..hummm...from when does the knowledge of good programming practices started being opinion based?

Comment: Moderators probably consider your question too broad for StackOverflow. It is expected that people ask practical questions that already include an attempt at solving the problem. Maybe you can consider revising your question?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades "Good programming practices" are opinions, and some people disagree about them. StackOverflow is generally meant for questions where the answer isn't an opinion; it's something that either works and meets the asker's requirements or it doesn't work and meet the asker's requirements. Something like "Which version of this code looks nicer?" or "Should I do **x** to make this more readable?" are asking for opinion. That isn't to say, however, that your question isn't something that's good to ask, just that StackOverflow might not be the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, as far as loops go I have a hard cutoff of three. If I ever hit three nested loops (not counting if/else conditions or try/catch conditions) then I know it's time to break it up into separate functions.

As far as tradeoffs, so long as the function you're running is run many times in quick succession (as in the lower tiers of a loop) there shouldn't be really any performance loss. There is always a slight overhead associated with making a function call, but luckily computers are really smart and they have these things call `temporal caches` where a cache is an area of *extremely* fast memory (read: SRAM). That will recognize and load your function call into the cache. Since accessing things already in the cache is effectively free (read times of a few ns) you won't really pay any performance loss for those extra function calls.

The usage of classes is *very* language dependant though. In javascript, everything is already an object, so you really shouldn't worry about wrapping functions in classes, though again there will be a slight overhead. For languages like Java however, you should endeavour to make a large number of small classes. The JVM is extremely optimized for talking between multiple classes and the JIT compiler shouldn't load up any of the extra "goo" involved in the classes unless you really need it.

In general though, performance is not what you should be making most of your decisions based on (performance is very 80/20, and all you usually need is the 80 of not doing anything overtly silly.) You should really try to follow a pattern that makes your code as readable as possible to other developers. It's pretty hard to define a hard and fast rule as there are many camps on the subject. In general though, for a starting programmer my advice would be to look at a LOT of code and try to understand what's happening. Try to rewrite portions of code in a more readable format if you can. There's enough open source code on Github that it should be pretty easy to do.

Also good programming practices have always been opinions, it's just that people remarkably agree sometimes.